# Comparing observed and predicted values across several measurements

Tags: multiple-regression, multiple-comparisons, normality-assumption, prediction

As a neuropsychology graduate student with some experience in statistics (I'm usually the guy other psychologists come to with statistics problems *after* trying it themselves but *before* seeing a statistician), I am investigating whether a medical treatment has an effect on cognitive measures (aside from curing the medical problem). I have been looking for a statistically sound method to approach the following problem (preferably using R) which will also pass muster with (medical) reviewers. I will try to explain the problem, which appears to be somewhat unusual - perhaps because of an error in my thinking.

I have data from two populations: a large group of controls, and a smaller group of patients (n ~ 20). In both groups, I have scores on a normally distributed cognitive scale at four time points (T0-T3), which in patients corresponds to a pre-treatment score (T0) and three post-treatment scores (T1-T3). As part of an accepted approach in neuropsychology (SRB-analysis; e.g. [Duff, 2012](http://acn.oxfordjournals.org/content/27/3/248.short)), I have used multiple regression on the control data to model scores at T1, T2 and T3 from demographics and baseline (T0) scores. This regression model is then used to predict scores at T1-T3 in patients, and change in individual patients is evaluated based on the difference between predicted and observed score at T1-T3 (as well as the prediction error/variability in controls). For a single patient that looks something like this:

```
                   T0      T1      T2      T3
Observed Score     100     105     106     107
Predicted Score    -       110     117     120
```

However, the analysis is intended for an audience that is used to group (rather than individual) analysis, and to (partially) oblige this audience I would like to compare the predictions in patients **as a group** with the observed scores. This group analysis presents with me with two problems:

1. Due to phenomena such as regression to the mean, practice effects, etc., the distribution of the predicted scores is different from the distribution of the observed scores. For example, regression to the mean decreases the spread in the predicted scores (as compared to observed scores).
2. Although data exploration (histograms, qq-plots, etc) suggest that difference scores (observed-predicted) are normally distributed, the group size (n ~20) is smaller than what is usually recommended as a minimum group size for approximate normality (n ~30).

I would like to answer two questions in the group analysis:

1. Are observed scores different from (/lower than) predicted scores?
2. At which time points (T1-T3) are observed scores lower than predicted scores?

As a first approximation, I have used one-sample t-tests on the difference scores (observed-predicted) with Bonferroni correction for multiple (3) comparisons. But that is clearly a non-optimal solution: it does not directly provide the omnibus test required to answer the first question and it assumes normality where that is at least somewhat doubtful.

Hence my question: what would be the optimal way to perform the group analysis?

Comment: I'm concerned about some of your reasoning/premises. Why would group-size relate to how near to normality the population distribution of difference sores might be? Recommended by whom? What did they actually recommend, and what justification did they offer?

Comment: I'm sorry for being slow to reply, but I only realized today that there were new comments to this question.

Comment: Yeah, sorry to come in on it so long after you posted.

Comment: Lost my edit. Regarding normality, the "rule of 30" is quoted in many sources, e.g., here: http://www.randomservices.org/random/sample/CLT.html. The reasoning as I understand it is that with distributions that are not too weird, with n>30 the central limit theorem implies that a normal approximation can reasonably be used. Of course you are right that sample size has no bearing on whether scores actually follow a normal distribution in the population.

Comment: Since this was indeed posted long ago, I will add that we have since then published these data using the t-test solution offered in my original question.

Comment: Many sources state this "rule" but the rule is so vague as to be of no value whatever - there is nothing special about 30 *in any sense*. In some cases n=2 is fine, in others n=200000 is not nearly enough (and we've seen at least one real example on site of actual cases where huge numbers like that were not sufficient). In fact the "rule" quite literally commits the fallacy of circular reasoning / begging the question (how do we know whether it's "too weird" other than by looking to see if the result were the case? If we have no other criterion then this "rule of 30" is contentless)

Comment: by the way if you have an answer to this question, please post it. There's a bounty on offer for a better answer than the present one.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a better answer either. I guess repeated measures ANOVA is reasonable if you assume normality. One possible alternative might be to set up a linear mixed model with subject as random term and observed-versus-predicted as the only fixed factor - though that also has it's own potential problems.

Comment: Regarding the rule of 30, I agree that it's circular but I guess you rarely know the population distribution. While it's vague, I guess that a sample size of around 30 is usually enough to reveal really major deviations from normality in your sample. Of course, you could still have drawn a normal-looking sample from a severely skewed population, but if you have theoretical reasons to think the distribution should be normal and it looks approximately normal then that's all you ever really have to go by, isn't it?

Comment: This additional condition to the usual rule is a very interesting suggestion; it may be worth pursuing its properties via a new question.

Comment: @Glen_b: I think the heuristic that 30 is roughly enough for normality comes from the fact that Binomial(n,p) normalized tends to the standard normal distribution in terms of CDF convergence, and the maximum absolute error is less than 1% when n ≥ 30 and p ∈ [1/3,2/3]. So if you take a sample of n i.i.d. r.v.s bounded by [0,1] that are no worse skewed, then the sample mean has distribution differing from normal by less than 1%. Of course, this is not the best heuristic. A better one is min(p,(1−p))·√n ≥ 2 (with continuity correction for the binomial) that ensure < 1% error for all n,p.

Comment: Perhaps, it's at least plausible.  If only all distributions were as nicely behaved as the binomial for $\frac13\leq p\leq\frac23$.

Answer (score 0):

GLM or general linear model, an option in SPSS, offers repeated measures analysis. Repeated measures analysis is useful for stacked data.

Repeated measures analysis is usually done with stacked data. Under repeated meaures, each observation, rather than each subject, is used as a case by SPSS.

Since you require something like a pairwise comparison, rather than a mere comparison of means, this option may be best suited for you.